# Can't figure out why Wix won't overwrite old version

Tags: c#, wix, installation

I can't figure out why WIX installer won't overwrite the old version of the program. It keeps just installing a new second program. Here's my wix coding... (yes i'm new to XML and WIX)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define AMTechEU_TargetDir=$(var.AMTechEU.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="AMTechEU" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.1" Manufacturer="AM Technologies" UpgradeCode="9a48ed21-f1a0-410f-babd-09b3c95a779c">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <MajorUpgrade
  AllowDowngrades="no"
  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
  IgnoreRemoveFailure="no"
  DowngradeErrorMessage="loc.NewerVersionInstalled"
  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>
```

Comment: Window MSI ignores the last digit of the version (I don't know who decided this) so try changing your version to 1.0.1.0 and see if it upgrades. You can also run your install with logging to get a better idea of what is happening. From the command line launch your installer "msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Upgrade Code. **The Upgrade Code must be identically to the previous version**s install package otherwise it could not identify itself as an Upgrade to the previous version.

To upgrade multiple installation packages by one new installation package you need to use the upgrade table.

Fix your version number, windows installer only use major.minor.build.

Comment: Thanks. Version number fixed it